# Display in loop elements from ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I try display in View using loop all elements from ViewBag

**My ViewBag (in controller class)**

```
ViewBag.MenuItems =
  (
     from components in _context.Components
     where components.ComponentName== "menuPosition"
     select new
     {
         controller = components.valueI,
         action = components.valueI,
      }
  ).ToList();
```

**My View**

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MenuItems)
   {
   <p>@item.controller</p>
   }
```

**I got error**

```
RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'controller'
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't use `ViewBag` to store complex objects anyway. I would create a `ViewModel` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewBag as List while looping it will treat viewbag element as MenuItem class object

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.MenuItems as List<MenuItem>)
{
    <p>@item.controller</p>
}
```

Add class

```
public class MenuItem
{
public string controller {get;set;}
public string action {get;set;}
}
```

In controller class use

```
ViewBag.MenuItems =
  (
     from components in _context.Components
     where components.ComponentName== "menuPosition"
     select new MenuItem
     {
         controller = components.valueI,
         action = components.valueI,
      }
  ).ToList();
```

Comment: I try this, but i got error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. ViewBag.MenuItems is not null (count 2 elements)

Comment: Why don't you add one class which will have properties as Controller and action as I editied in answer